# How to reformat tweets, replacing single quotes with escaped quotes consistently

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, input-filtering

Currently, I have a method, which will be shown below, designed to remove all the single quotes and newline characters for tweets that were retrieved using the twitter API. The newline works every time, but for some reason, despite that, the replacing character only works half the time. This replacement method is called exactly one line before the write file, so I am doubtful that for some reason it misses iterations. The tweets seem to filter randomly. I can't explain why sometimes it works.  Strange note. Removing the if statement with the x.replace("\", "\\'"); results in nothing being filtered.

Thanks in advance.

```
public static String replace(String x) {
    String replaced = x;


        if (x.contains("'")) {
            replaced = x.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'");
        }
        if(x.contains("\n") || x.contains("\r")){
            replaced = x.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");
        }

        System.out.println(replaced);

    return replaced;
}
```

Edit: Looking into it, the if statement activates, but a small minority of the time, some tweets simple go to the replaceAll line and don't get replaced. Why not? I have no clue.

Sample Data: https://justpaste.it/15c6t
First screw up is "You're" line 20.

Comment: if you want to remove single quotes  why you `replaced = x.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'");` replacing it with this?

Comment: simply replace it with blank

Comment: I'm not trying to remove the single quotes. I'm trying to escape it so I can use it in a third party program called "weka" for data analysis. I need to replace the single quote with the escaped version, which is \'

Comment: Yes. it might be possible you miss some iteration. And what you talking about `x.replace("\", "\\'"); `

Comment: It isn't missing iterations. It's literally just not replacing it as it should. Going in debug mode, it completely skips over it. Also, it seems that the shortcut character worked in the post. I didn't notice. It should be x.replace("'", "\\\\'");

Comment: can you give your real data string which skipping

Comment: I put it in the question. There's a link. Funnily enough, it hits all of them the 2nd time around if I call the method twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141281/discussion-between-hitesh-ghuge-and-xenorosth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there were cases where the first replace method was being interfered with the second replace method. When separating the two into two different methods (while awkward), it functioned as it should have.

```
public static String replace(String x) { //Cleans the single quotes
    String replaced = x;
        if (replaced.contains("'")) {
            replaced = x.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'");             
        }
    return replaced;
}

public static String removeEnters(String x){ //Removes any enters
    String replaced = x;
    if(replaced.contains("\n") || x.contains("\r")){
            replaced = x.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " ");
    }
    return replaced;
}
```